# How is Im$[(z_1+z_2)(z_2+z_3)(z_3+z_1)]/(z_1 z_2 z_3) = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

How is Im$\frac{[(z_1+z_2)(z_2+z_3)(z_3+z_1)]}{(z_1 z_2 z_3)} = 0$ if $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|=1$? My book says it is because $\frac{[(z_1+z_2)(z_2+z_3)(z_3+z_1)]}{(z_1 z_2 z_3)}$ is equal to its conjugate, but I don't see how it is possible. Would someone please help?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: If $|z|=1$, then the conjugate of $z$ is $z^{-1}$. So the conjugate of $$\frac{(z_1+z_2)(z_2+z_3)(z_3+z_1)}{z_1z_2z_3}$$
is
$$\frac{(z_1^{-1}+z_2^{-1})(z_2^{-1}+z_3^{-1})(z_3^{-1}+z_1^{-1})}{z_1^{-1}z_2^{-1}z_3^{-1}}.$$
Can you go from there?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown You should probably put this as an answer